# Google maps rectangle mouseDown and mouseUp events fail to fire at borders

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Rectangle shape is to be made editable on mouseover event and setEditable should be false on mouseout event. However, when I try to edit this shape by mousedown event at the edges, the mousedown event is not getting executed (doesn't see the console printing it). Since mouseout event is fired and the setEditable value is false and edit never happens. This behavior is observed only in Google Chrome. In IE and Firefox the mousedown is NOT getting fired yet the rectangle borders are editable as desired.

Following is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>User-editable Shapes</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    // This example adds a user-editable rectangle to the map.

    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 44.5452,
          lng: -78.5389
        },
        zoom: 9
      });

      // [START region_rectangle]
      var bounds = {
        north: 44.599,
        south: 44.490,
        east: -78.443,
        west: -78.649
      };

      // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true.
      var myRectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        bounds: bounds,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      // [END region_rectangle]
      myRectangle.setMap(map);

      var isMouseDown = false;

      google.maps.event.addListener(myRectangle, "mouseover", function(event) {
        myRectangle.setEditable(true);
        console.log("Mouse over");
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(myRectangle, "mouseout", function(event) {
        if (!isMouseDown) {
          myRectangle.setEditable(false);
        }
        console.log("Mouse out");
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(myRectangle, "mousedown", function(event) {
        isMouseDown = true;
        console.log("Mouse down");
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(myRectangle, "mouseup", function(event) {
        isMouseDown = false;
        console.log("Mouse up");
      });

    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify the issue in short, The mousedown event is not triggered at the edges of the region in Google Maps only in Chrome browser. However, it works fine in Firefox and IE. Is this right. Correct me if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: When I run the script in IE and Firefox, I don't see the Mouse Down or Mouse Up events getting fired either. But the rectangular boundaries are still editable. However, in Chrome neither the events are fired nor the rectangle is editable. Sample code can be tested at following URL:
http://jsbin.com/zebeheduha/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solution:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Edit Rectangle Workaround</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 44.5452, lng: -78.5389},
    zoom: 9
  });

  var bounds = {
    north: 44.599,
    south: 44.490,
    east: -78.443,
    west: -78.649
  };

  // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true.
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: false
  });
  rectangle.setMap(map);

  var isMouseDown = false;

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "mouseover", function(event) {
          rectangle.setEditable(true);
        console.log("Mouse over");
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "mouseout", function(event) {
        var mouse_event;
        for (key in event) {
            if (event[key] instanceof MouseEvent) {
                mouse_event = event[key];
            }
        }
        if (mouse_event && mouse_event.target && mouse_event.target.parentElement) {
            console.log(mouse_event.target.parentElement.style.cursor);
            if (/closedhand_8_8/.test(mouse_event.target.parentElement.style.cursor)){
                return;
            }
        }
        rectangle.setEditable(false);
            console.log("Mouse out");
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```